# Using node.js to verify a X509 certificate with CA cert

Tags: node.js, ssl, certificate, verification, ca

I am looking for a node.js way to verify a client certificate in X509 format with a CA certificate which was given to me (none of those are created/managed by me, my software only has to verify what is beeing sent to it).

I have found several modules for this job, however I am having issues with each of them:

- [X509](https://github.com/Southern/node-x509) is able to do it using `x509.verify(cert, CABundlePath, cb)`, however it needs to read the certificates from FS, and I am having them in memory already. This is cumbersome as it will be done with each web request which reaches my app.
- It seems like [PKI.js](https://pkijs.org/) is able to do it, however their examples don't work for me but complain about missing files, so I can't even try it out.
- I tried [node-forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge), but while I am unsure if I use it correctly (they don't have any API documentation) its throwing a `forge.pki.BadCertificate` error from `forge.pki.verifyCertificateChain(caStore, [ cer ], cb)`.
- When trying [pem](https://www.deineagentur.com/projects/pem/module-pem.html#.verifySigningChain), using a simple `pem.verifySigningChain(cer, [ ca ], cb)` would throw some error complaining about loading a file from `/var/...`. Even if it would work, I would avoid using this lib as its relying on the *openssl command line tool*, which I would like to avoid

Now I feel pretty stupid because I failed to get this simple task done with any of the above modules. Could someone point me to a simple solution which will allow me to verify the signature/validity of a X509 certificate using a given CA certificate? :s

[edit] Basically I would need `openssl verify -verbose -CAfile ca-crt.pem  client1-crt.pem` in `Node.js` but ***without*** dependencies to the openssl command line tool and ***without*** temporarily saving the certs to disk.

[edit2] Would it be possible to just use https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_verify_verify_object_signature_signatureformat?

Comment: This is an excellently written question. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally managed to do it using `node-forge`. Heres a working code example:

```
let pki = require('node-forge').pki;
let fs = require('fs');

let caCert;
let caStore;

try {
    caCert = fs.readFileSync('path/to/ca-cert.pem').toString();
    caStore = pki.createCaStore([ caCert ]);
} catch (e) {
    log.error('Failed to load CA certificate (' + e + ')');
    return....;
}

try {
    pki.verifyCertificateChain(caStore, [ cert ]);
} catch (e) {
    return handleResponse(new Error('Failed to verify certificate (' + e.message || e + ')'));
}
```

Both certificates shall be given in base64 encoded PEM format/js string.

`verifyCertificateChain` checks the certifitate validity (`notBefore`/`notAfter`) as well as verifies the given CA chain.

I am not 100% sure if this is the best approach, or if this library is doing a good job, since their source code of `verifyCertificateChain` is full of `#TODO`s, so maybe this is not ready for production? 
But at least I have a somewhat working solution. Probably it would be better to create a node module which wraps the `libssl` c calls, but thats just a lot of effort for this small task.

Comment: where is `cert` defined?

Comment: Its the certificate you want to verify. Its provided by you.

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to convert a PEM-encoded (string) certificate to a forge cert object: `const cert = pki.certificateFromPem(certificate.data);`
(certificate.data was provided in my Electron app on the `certificate-error` event.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also do like this if you want to check the using the client certificates from the http request directly :

```
// retrieve certificates from the request ( in der format )
clientCert = req.connection.getPeerCertificate(true).raw.toString('base64'))
```

Method to convert the der certificate to pem and verify against the castore.

```
  const caCert = fs....
  const ca = pki.certificateFromPem(caCert)
  const caStore = pki.createCaStore([ ca ])

  const verify = (clientCert, next) => {
    try {
      const derKey = forge.util.decode64(clientCert)
      const asnObj = forge.asn1.fromDer(derKey)
      const asn1Cert = pki.certificateFromAsn1(asnObj)
      const pemCert = pki.certificateToPem(asn1Cert)
      const client = pki.certificateFromPem(pemCert)
      return pki.verifyCertificateChain(caStore, [ client ], cb)
    } catch (err) {
      next(new Error(err))
    }
  }
```

I did not find a better way to verify the client "der" certificate from the `request`.

fas3r

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
const fs = require('fs'), pki = require('node-forge').pki
var ca = pki.certificateFromPem(fs.readFileSync('ca.pem', 'ascii'))
var client = pki.certificateFromPem(fs.readFileSync('client.pem', 'ascii'))
try {
    if (!ca.verify(client)) throw 'verify failed'
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

try/catch was required, because .verify threw an error (instead of returning false) in my case.